# Must declare the scalar variable "@maxprice"

Tags: sql

This is my sql code -

```
declare @maxprice int --1
set @maxprice = 1000 --2
select @maxprice --3
```

I can execute these combinations 1,2 and 1,2,3 without errors. But, when I execute 1,2 first and 3 later, i get the error i mentioned.

I am not able to understand why this happens. Shouldn't the select @maxprice be similar to a regular select statement ?

Comment: When Execution completes it flush all the variable you declared, and when execute only 3rd statement, it doesn't find any declaration of `@maxprice`..

Comment: @AdeelAhmed - I am a beginner. I don't know all those things now. Where can i learn them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL statements like these are executed in as a block, and commands and definitions are only valid within the block. As soon as the block is finished, any declared variables go out of scope, and are undefined.

So, when you execute just line 3, SQL server does not know or check if you have previously done something with the same variable, and naturally complains that the variable is not defined.

If this was not so, and once declared variables remained in scope (e.g. for the duration of the session), the system would have to take great care to resolve clashes between, for example, `@maxprice` being declare with a `int` in one procedure, and with a `money` type in another.

A more detailed discussion of variables and scoping rules in SQL Server, can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Is this what you meant - declare and select with int, then repeat with money ? If that is the case, then there should not be a problem if the declared variable remains in scope. Re-declaring it would/could kill the scope of the old one.

Comment: I'm not saying it couldn't be done :) I'm saying it's not done like that in SQL Server, and I think the reasons why is that there are too much possible side effects for a feature that is not that useful.

Comment: I see codes that declare variables. How do i know where the scope ends ? Also, is there a way to make a "permanent" variable, ie whose scope is forever ?